# Power automate outlook actionable adaptive cards not getting rendered within the email

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have a power automate where it sends an email to a specific user with two text boxes within the email body (implemented through outlook adaptive template) asking few information.

I have followed below blog to implement the adaptive message. The power automate is able to send the message success fully, but when the user opens the message whether in outlook desktop/web out look, unable to see these boxes over there.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Would be easier to help if you update the question with the adaptive card json file attached. I would be happy to take a look :)

Comment: Hello,
 I am using below JSON.

I don't see option to attach the JSON. 
Below is the blog reference from here exactly the same JSON I used to replicate in my Power Automate.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/actionable-outlook-message-using-adaptive-card-connected-to-sharepoint-using-pow/

Comment: Did you register a provider for your message? Done here: https://outlook.office.com/connectors/oam/publish

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/actionable-outlook-message-using-adaptive-card-connected-to-sharepoint-using-pow/

Based on above implementation I am trying to use actionable adaptive cards  in email.
What to register here. Could you please mention a bit more?

Comment: From that great article, there is a link to this documentation from Microsoft on setting up a provider for your actinable cards: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/email-dev-dashboard See my above link for how to access the dashboard.